# what does sendmail_path mean?

Tags: php, email

I'm working on a client site and what is typically a very simple process has me pretty tied up feeling atm, but I get it to send emails!!

The script is just on a simple contact form. I'm having her contact support, but in the mean time, when I run phpinfo, the only thing I see different frmo a server of my own where I have no problems sending emails with the mail() function is the sendmail path.

My client site has this setting: sendmail_path: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -fname@site.com

my own server doesn't specify the -f[email]. So what exactly does this mean? I haven't found anything very solid on google yet. There are a number of places that this could be failing, but figured this was one area worth looking into.

What exactly is the -f[email] in the sendmail_path mean?

Comment: I would have thought it was self evident but it's simply the default *"from"* address - [see the manual page](http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/man/sendmail.html).

Comment: I would have thought that was what sendmail_from was, lol. can it send ONLY from that email?

Comment: `sendmail_*` are just php ini configs - not entirely sure where *PHP* applies the `from` but whether you use it or the *CLI* switches makes no difference - guess it's just what the sysadmin was familiar with.  I don't think it means it can *only* send from that address - I'd expect you to be able to override it in the headers.

Answer (score 1):

It is  a mail transport agent which can be found in `php.ini conf file`.

A sample structure would be

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -F"Full Name" -f'emailaddress@example.com'
```